# Trying to send form data from html to Controller in Stripes Framework, But it is not allowing

Tags: java, stripes

This is my code which tries to send form data from html to controller

```
$("#btnsubmitsignup").live("click", function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();         
        var firstName = $("#firstName").val();
        var lastName = $("#lastName").val();            
        var email = $("#email").val();
        var password = $("#password").val();            

        $.post("/app/signup/signUp",{firstName:firstName,lastName:lastName,email:email,password:password })
            .done(function(data) {
                //$('#enquiry').reveal();
                $(".enqurymsg").show();
                $(".enqurymsg .enqsuccessmessage h5").text("Thank you for Sign Up").addClass("enqsuccess");
        }).fail(function () {
            $(".enqurymsg").show();
            $(".enqurymsg .enqsuccessmessage h5").text("Error in Sign      Up").addClass("enqerror");
        });
    });

   @UrlBinding("/signup/{$event}/{activationKey}")

   public class RegistrationAction extends BaseActionBean {

   public Resolution signUp() {

        User user = new User();
        user.setFirstName(firstName);
        user.setLastName(lastName);
        user.setEmail(email);
        user.setPassword(password);
   }
 }
```

Getting the Following Exception

Exceptional Detail:

```
net.sourceforge.stripes.exception.SourcePageNotFoundException: Here's how it is. Someone (quite possibly the Stripes Dispatcher) neede
d to get the source page resolution. But no source page was supplied in the request, and unless you override ActionBeanContext.getSour
cePageResolution() you're going to need that value. When you use a <stripes:form> tag a hidden field called '_sourcePage' is included.
 If you write your own forms or links that could generate validation errors, you must include a value  for this parameter. This can be
 done by calling request.getServletPath().
        at net.sourceforge.stripes.action.ActionBeanContext.getSourcePageResolution(ActionBeanContext.java:239)
        at net.sourceforge.stripes.controller.DispatcherHelper.handleValidationErrors(DispatcherHelper.java:388)
        at net.sourceforge.stripes.controller.DispatcherServlet.handleValidationErrors(DispatcherServlet.java:270)
        at net.sourceforge.stripes.controller.DispatcherServlet.service(DispatcherServlet.java:156)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
        at net.sourceforge.stripes.controller.DynamicMappingFilter$2.doFilter(DynamicMappingFilter.java:431)
        at net.sourceforge.stripes.controller.StripesFilter.doFilter(StripesFilter.java:260)
        at net.sourceforge.stripes.controller.DynamicMappingFilter.doFilter(DynamicMappingFilter.java:418)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1476)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:499)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:557)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1086)
```

I am getting the above exception while trying to send the form data from html to controller

Comment: Before people vote you down, i suggest you write some explaining as for what you are asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens when you have validation error and stripe does not know which page issued the request as it is an ajax request.Use form sumit form submission after validation. Also try to check which validation is failing in user domain.